# How to execute selenium scripts parallely in multiple test environments?

Tags: selenium, grid, webdriver, testng

I have to execute my regression test suite in multiple test environments (ex:- QA,QAH,QAT). The URL for 3 environments is different and user credentials are different. My TestNG xml is as shown below:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="4" name="Suite" parallel="tests">
<test name="Test1">
 <classes>
  <class name="com.seleniumgrid.TestScripts.Test1"/>
</classes>
</test> 
<test name="Test2"> 
   <classes>
  <class name="com.seleniumgrid.TestScripts.Test2"/>
  </classes>
</test>
<test name="Test3">   
   <classes>
  <class name="com.seleniumgrid.TestScripts.Test3"/>
  </classes>
</test>
<test name="Test4">   
   <classes>
  <class name="com.seleniumgrid.TestScripts.Test4"/>
  </classes>
</test>

</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

For example if have 3 remote machines, i have to execute the above suite parallely in the 3 systems using Firefox browser.

The solution should be in such a way that, in future if some more environments come into picture, suite should execute in those environments as well in parallely.

I guess, this can be achieved by using Selenium GRID.
Can anyone give me some suggestions/Ideas on this?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Selenium Grid is best...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by having glance at below framework. This depends on how your framework is designed. You can do parametrized testing. Also using GRID is good idea. You can use dataProvider from testNG and read data from Excel file and pass it to appropriate script.

https://github.com/selenium-webdriver-software-testing/kspl-selenium-helper

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you!! for your quick response. I will check the framework and will let you know.